# Proper organization of server side code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm relatively new to rails, but I've made a few basic CRUD apps. However, this time, I'm making something different, and I'm not sure how to organize it.

It's essentially a one page app. The user fills out a form, and the code does some calculations based on those values. I have all the code written, but it's all just sitting in the controller. I'm assuming that this isn't correct.

There are two parts:

- Using an external API, 2 constant arrays are generated. I need these variables to be global, or at least accessible for the calculator function.
- I have a function that takes some inputs from the form that also calls other functions. A simplified version is below. I could put all the code into one function if that's necessary. I have them separate just so that the code is more readable.

  `def calc(input)
    func1(input)
    func2(input)
    # do more stuff
    return answer #I need to show this in the view
  end`

  `def func1(a)
  end`

  `def func2(b)
  end`

So, where should I put each part of this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your controllers thin, you can keep business logic at Service Objects.
Just create "services" directory at "app", add there some class like "user_searcher.rb".
And call it in the controller, passing all necessary data.

Such technique will help you to isolate business logic and incapsulate it in separate class.

BTW read this article http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Comment: Wow that article is extremely helpful! Thanks, it answered some other questions that I had as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think, from what I understand of you question, is this code should be placed in the helper classes. If you have dedicated class for this calculation, you can use class attributes to access array to access anywhere in the class or declare them constant, in case they are constant.

I don't think making global is a good practice, just because this is needed in some other function, instead return that variable and pass them as parameter where they are needed.